# JavaScript variables to PHP Form on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I use the following code :

```
// Datepicker / Timepicker jQuery Script
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format : "YYYY-MM-DD"
}).on("dp.change", function (e) {
    datetimepicker1 = $('#datetimepicker1').val();
});
```

How do I get my PHP form to get the variable 'datetimepicker1' on form submission to send it to my SQL database.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You can pass the variables through `$.ajax`.

Comment: You should make an Ajax query :)

Comment: @Ms. Nehal - so close to 1000..... :)) well done... one more accept / upvote and you're there!!!

Comment: Thanks @gavgrif, just hope my answers are that well that it will be usefull for users, which would help me increase my score as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as posted in the comments - you can do it through AJAX, or you can set a hidden input value in your form so that it passes with the rest of the form on submission. The following creates a hidden input which you would put into your existing form, and then on the change in the date-time picker, will add the value to this hidden input. The form can then submit as normal and the value will be passed with the rest of the form variables.

```
//input in form
<input type='hidden' name='new_dateTime' value='' />


// Datepicker / Timepicker jQuery Script
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format : "YYYY-MM-DD"}
    ).on("dp.change", function (e) {
        datetimepicker1 = $('#datetimepicker1').val();
$('[name = new_dateTime]').val(datetimepicker1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

where `#form`is the form id like this:

`<form id="form" method="post">`

Here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#form').submit(function() { 

     e.preventDefault();// Datepicker / Timepicker jQuery Script
     $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format : "YYYY-MM-DD"}
       ).on("dp.change", function (e) {
        datetimepicker1 = $('#datetimepicker1').val();
    });
  });
});
```

You can also try this :

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
```

Changes in jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#submit').click(function() { 

     e.preventDefault();// Datepicker / Timepicker jQuery Script
     $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format : "YYYY-MM-DD"}
       ).on("dp.change", function (e) {
        datetimepicker1 = $('#datetimepicker1').val();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an AJAX request on dp.change event, It will be something like:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
format : "YYYY-MM-DD"}
).on("dp.change", function (e) {
    datetimepicker1 = $('#datetimepicker1').val();
    $.ajax({
       url: 'AJAX.php', //PHP file to send value
       method: 'GET', //or POST
       data: {date_time: datetimepicker1},
       success: function(response) {
         console.log(response);
       }
    });
});
```

In AJAX.php file, use `$_GET` to trive the data and pass to SQL/Database.

Comment: **Deprecation Notice**: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Which version of jQuery?